# Make woocommerce items fit full page or remove the padding (responssive). Currently the margins/ paddings change from desktop to mobile view

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Desktop view looks like this:

[image: desktop]

Mobile view like this:

[image: mobile]

My product catalog (woocommerce) images do not fit full screen. where/how can I modify this? I think it might be theme related. I want to remove that right padding on desktop view, and the middle/bottom/top padding on mobile, basically the elements taking full width, sticking to each other. I have looked for days, tried to play with the console and on/off settings but no luck. Would greatly appreciate guidance here :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using bootstrap use col-md-4 as a class of every div

use whatever you want from 1 to 12 instead of 4

for help try to post with code .

thanks. happy coding

Comment: Thanks but what do I use to remove that padding? I have tried full width, all padding, nothing seems to work. which code could help? I used the google console and literally went through the entire thing disabling and trying to modify code, I have no idea where this can be modified.